# youtube-dl option for getting video titles and NOT downloading videos

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I want to get video titles from a video list.


`--flat-playlist` option returns video id's, and I can't find an options that returns video titles.

```
youtube-dl --flat-playlist "https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/openid-and-oauth2-securing-angular-apps"
[pluralsight:course] openid-and-oauth2-securing-angular-apps: Downloading JSON metadata
[download] Downloading playlist: Securing Angular Apps with OpenID Connect and OAuth 2
[pluralsight:course] playlist Securing Angular Apps with OpenID Connect and OAuth 2: Collected 58 video ids (downloading 58 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 58
[download] Downloading video 2 of 58
[download] Downloading video 3 of 58
...
```

`--get-filename` option and `--get-title` option, prints the name just for the first video, then they throw `ExtractorError('No video formats found')`:

```
youtube-dl --get-title "https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/openid-and-oauth2-securing-angular-apps" --verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the way to pull a list of videos without downloading them, the issue with your query is that the URL you are using requires you to be signed in (and youtube-dl doesn't have access to your credentials)

Both this

```
 youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/@Wondrium/videos -e
```

and this

```
 youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/@Wondrium/videos --get-title
```

works.

For example:
[image: Example]